# audio problems ubuntu 22.04 profile:off

Tags: drivers, sound, kubuntu, pulseaudio, alsa

ive tried everything but the audio just isnt working.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Exvw.png)
im on ubuntu 22.04 using intel SST comet lake drivers
i've tried alsamixer,pulseaudio, pretty much all the tutorials on fixing it but it just wont work
the driver shows up in settings in audio as a device but the only option is "profile:off"
alfamixer wont open with the following error: cannot open mixer: No such file or directory

any advice would be appreciated, i cant use my device at all
ps: audio does work when using headphones for example